# Android Kernel OTG

Tags: android, usb-otg

How can I use an app to detect when the otg cable is plugged in and when it's not?

Is there an intent for otg cables like the one below for usb devices: "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"

I have created an app but it only detects a flash drive and not an otg cable:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private TextView mInfo;
    private Logger mLogger;
    private HashMap<UsbDevice, UsbDataBinder> mHashMap = new HashMap<UsbDevice, UsbDataBinder>();
    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);

        mLogger = new Logger(this);
        mLogger.setMode(Logger.MODE_TOAST);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        usbConnection();
    }

    private void usbConnection() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        registerReceiver(mUsbAttachReceiver , filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        registerReceiver(mUsbDetachReceiver , filter);

        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        showDevices();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbDetachReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbAttachReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
    };

    BroadcastReceiver mUsbDetachReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null) {
                    // call your method that cleans up and closes communication with the device
                    UsbDataBinder binder = mHashMap.get(device);
                    if (binder != null) {
                        binder.onDestroy();
                        mHashMap.remove(device);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Attached!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    BroadcastReceiver mUsbAttachReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                showDevices();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Detached!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                            UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            // call method to set up device communication
                            UsbDataBinder binder = new UsbDataBinder(mUsbManager, device);
                            mHashMap.put(device, binder);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void showDevices() {
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            //your code
            mLogger.log("usb", "name: " + device.getDeviceName() + ", " +
                    "ID: " + device.getDeviceId());
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceName() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceId() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getProductId() + "\n");
            mInfo.append(device.getVendorId() + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never tried USB OTG, but from https://github.com/shakalaca/USB-OTG-Manager you can use

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.hardware.action.USB_OTG_DEVICE_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.hardware.action.USB_OTG_DEVICE_DISCONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.hardware.action.USB_OTG_ERROR" />
    <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.usbotg.ACTION_ERROR_OK" />

    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />

</intent-filter>
```

From the documentation:

> USB OTG Manager
>
> This software is originally designed for Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S.
>   Since OTG is enabled in kernel, I'm wondering why I can't access my
>   memory stick. So I've created this little application for reading
>   books on my thumb disk, and happily ever after ! :D
>
> Supported Phone:
>   * Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S (4.0.2.A.042, 4.0.2.A.062)
>   * Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro (4.0.2.A.042, 4.0.2.A.058)
>   * Samsung Galaxy Nexus
>
> Supported USB Device:
>   * FAT USB memory stick
>   * Card Reader

related project: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

you're on your own boat now.

Comment: How to use this on my s3 neo i9301i ?